# processing messages in order we receive from MQ with multithreading using spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

We get trades from various exchanges and we need to load trades in a same order we receive from MQ, the reason we retain in same order is some times exchange may send change and delete record type of same trade, in this case we need to process change before delete. I noticed each message taking 21 milli secs (xml -> jaxb object-->pojo-->db) to load in our system. Exchanges drops a xml messages in MQ. With Spring integration how can I improve the trade load taking of 21 milli seconds/msg to some where around 10 millisecs, at the same time need to retain same order and should be grace fully terminate the process.

I have jaxb converter which convert xml to jaxb object , then other converter which convert the nested jaxb objects to single java entity object and then hibernate using to load java entity object to databse.

Gary,Pls let me know if you are clear with this question.

Answer (score 1):

> does this approach guarantees to the load to db in same order we receive from MQ

Only if the pollers use a single thread.

> does it guarantee all the messages in queue channel to process gracefully

No; and even you uss the orderly shutdown mechanism before closing the context, you still risk message loss (e.g. due to power failure). The transaction commits as soon as the message is added to the queue.

If you have to retain order, the safest configuration is to set `concurrent-consumers` to 1 (the default).

**EDIT:**

Since your operations are by nature serial - 2 convertions + store; there is no possibility to parallelize your flow for each trade. So, if you need to retain order, you are out of luck.

One way you could improve your flow performance is to somehow partition your data and use multiple inbound channel adapters with different message selectors, say by stock ticker, or stock ticker first letter.

Of course, this would require the exchange to set the ticker symbol in a header; which you said is not possible.

So you might have to put some intermediate partitioning into your flow - write to some other set of MQ queues (partitioned) and then consume your real business flow from those queues.

Comment: thanks for response Gary.. I need to process over million records or some times even more..my requirement is to process the messages we received in  a same order. can you advice me using multithreading with Spring integration how can I achieve?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Spring Integration (or Spring at all, in fact) - if you __must__ retain order then you __must__ use a single consumer. It would be better to re-examine why you need to retain the order. Perhaps you can have the producer insert some sequence header to avoid the problem.

Comment: producers are from exchanges, so can't expect them to add header with sequence.I would like to split a task to multiple subtasks and would like to assign each task a thread. as you said i will use single consumer which read and drops in queue channel transformer;. then second thread  transforms from transform channel and drops the output to other queue channel dbchannel. at the end service activator reads this messages from dbchannel and load to db..i still can use 3 threads to process a msg right with integration? pls let me know if this approach is wrong

Comment: Your requirements are not at all clear to me; if you need to transform, transform, then process in a DB, then they have to be performed serially for each message; depositing in a queue channel will serve no purpose at all. Comments are not a good way to clarify - I suggest you edit your question with a detailed explanation of exactly what you want to do with each message and where you perceive the performance bottleneck might be. However, I fear your requirements are conflicting (performance Vs. ordering).